# get date from file and automatically timestamp using first 6 digits of filename

Tags: directory, timestamp, filenames, daemon, monitor

I wish to find files in a directory quickly by looking up the timestamp related to the document when first created. Eg, if I have an invoice dated 15 January 2018, I would name this 180115. I want to time stamp this files in a directory with date in format yymmdd. Date should be taken from first 6 digits of filename (filename created manually). EG# 190922-inv.pdf will receive timestamp:

`$ ls -l 190922-inv.pdf 
-rw-r--r-- 1 mx mx 0 Sep 22 12:11 190922-inv.pdf`

hour doesn't matter.

I have created alias `td='touch -d'`

I have been manually typing `td 190914 190914*` to effect all files starting with timestamp, but would like to automate this. Ideally I would like to set up a daemon to monitor the directory for changes and run the above command automatically. My skill set is a bit below this and would appreciate any incremental help.